# Show if the revision of subrepos changed, or if they are dirty

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I have a mercurial repository (main repo) with several sub repositories.

I need a mercurial command to show if the revision of a sub repo changed (including information on old and new revision) in the working copy or if the sub repo state is dirty.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean with "revision of the sub-repo changed"? Should is sufficei f new revisions have been added, or only if the working active revision changed (that's what matters for the parent repo as it records only the sub-repos rev which it depends on)

Comment: I try to describe the use case: I update to a certain main repo revision, thus leads to a certain revision for every sub repo. Afterwards I can update some sub repos to a different revision (than the sub repo revision fixed in the main repo revision). Finally I'd like to generate a report where these changes are listed. Does this help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most mercurial commands accept the `-S` or `--subrepos` flag. Thus by calling `hg st -S` you get a list of all changed files which include those in the sub-repos, if their state differs from the state recorded in the .hgsubstate file:

```
$ cd opengfx/
$ hg st
$ hg id
10065545725a tip
$ cd ..
$ hg st -S
M opengfx/.hgtags
M opengfx/Makefile
A opengfx/lang/japanese.lng
$ cat .hgsubstate 
785bc42adf236f077333c55c58490cce16367e92 opengfx
```

As to your wish to obtain the actual revisions, that's AFAIK not possible with one command. However you can always check the status of the individual sub-repos like above or can check them from the main repo by giving mercurial another path to operate on:

```
$ hg id -R opengfx
10065545725a tip
```

In order to get the status of each repo compared to what is required by the parent repo, I'd resort to some simple bash:

```
for i in $(cat .hgsubstate | cut -d\  -f2); do echo $i is at $(hg id -R $i) but parent requires $(cat .hgsubstate | grep $i | cut -d\  -f1); done
```

which gives output like

```
opengfx is at 10065545725a tip but parent requires 785bc42adf236f077333c55c58490cce16367e92
```

In a similar fashion you can also check whether the state is modified by using `hg st` instead of `hg id`.